# Error Laravel Password Reset: Column 'email' Cannot Be Null

Tags: laravel, authentication, passwords, forgot-password

I'm working on a Laravel application where I have implemented the password reset feature. However, I'm consistently running into the following error:

`SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'email' cannot be null (Connection: main, SQL: insert into password_resets (email, token, created_at) values (?, $2y$10$sFSxC9pgIbmRisHh4RZK5.j0cZNLlmogdlbiokfnKDLoSv4ng.SHW, 2024-01-29 14:44:11))",`

Here's my code snippet from the **'sendResetPasswordEmail'** function:

```
public function sendResetPasswordEmail(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate(['email' => 'required|email']);

    $email = $request->input('email');

    $status = Password::sendResetLink(['email' => $email]);

    return $status === Password::RESET_LINK_SENT
        ? back()->with(['status' => __($status)])
        : back()->withErrors(['email' => __($status)]);
}
```

This is the body of my post request:

```
{
    "email": "ilovato@example.com"
}
```

My Pathetic Attempt at Debugging:

- I have confirmed that the 'email' is present in the request body and extracted correctly.
- I've verified my Laravel version, ensuring that it is up-to-date and [follows the current documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/passwords#password-reset-link-handling-the-form-submission).
- I've made the 'email' field nullable in the password_resets table. However, it registers as an null value.

Comment: Do you happen to have a user in your users table with a null or empty email address?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/passwords uses `Password::sendResetLink($request->only('email'));` - have you tried that?

Comment: Before proceeding further you may want to ask yourself why you would need to override the built-in method, and why you would mess with the database to the point where you have wrong column names.

Comment: The `sendResetLinkResponse` and `sendResetLinkFailedResponse` methods are there to customize the response, if that's your goal.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was that in my Users table in the database, the email field had a capital 'E' like 'Email.' However, Laravel by default searches for 'email' with a lowercase 'e,' and that's why.

If you don't want to modify the column's name on your database you can paste the following code on your User's model:

```
public function getEmailForPasswordReset(): string
{
        return $this->Email;
}
```

This code will overwrite the getEmailForPasswordReset on your User's model and you can customize the field that's going to be researched. Hope it helps some lost soul like mine!